# Equal item margin in multicolumn list

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have a long list which I would like to display in multicolumn mode. For simplicity let’s each item is one-line only. I would like items to be evenly spaced and aligned to the top. This works correctly if there is no margin around items.

However, I would like to add some space. Alas, using margin for li:

`ul {-webkit-column-count: 3; column-count: 3; -moz-column-count: 3; list-style-type: none}
li { margin: 5px}`

breaks top-alignment:

[image: Firefox renders first column below the other two, other browsers are not better]

The only solution I found is to use `li {border: 5px solid white}`
This solves the problem for Firefox, but Safari breaks the border (which looks like a bug to me BTW):

[image: Broken borders in Safari]

Is there any solution which works for all the popular browsers?

My sample code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/L59y0d06/

Comment: You need a [mcve] *in your question*

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure this isn't possible.

Comment: What isn’t possible? Achieving the goal? It works in Firefox, so at least it is possible there.